# Mac OS and PackageMaker: Allowing user to choose language during installation

Tags: cocoa, macos, internationalization, packagemaker

I am implementing a Mac application. Its Windows version is already implemented. Now I am facing the following issue:
implementation of the new package with multiple languages. I.e., for the Windows version of the software, when executing the installation file, the user can choose the language in which the application should be installed. I want this feature to be included in the Mac version.

Currently in the Mac version multiple language support is implemented using NSLocalizedString so that the app chooses a language according to the system language preference and the installation package is localized.

However, I specifically want the users to be able to choose the installation language of the app when installing. I am using PackageMaker now. Please help to solve this issue. I have been trying to implement this feature for several months, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The official recommendation from Apple is that you shouldn't do that; just include all of the localization to the app just as you already do. 
So, if it is not the requirement imposed on you by your employer, just don't do that and implement more useful things on your app.

The English user, who chose to install just English version, might suddenly marry a Japanese, who might want to use it in Japanese!

Comment: hi Yuji,the client is insisting on this feature.This is client's requirement that there should be option for English user to install the application in english and the same for French user.Please guide to solve this issue...

Comment: Does the client understand that with both localizations installed, the user can choose which language to use when the app is run? Maybe the client doesn't understand that point... Or does the client really insist on having the ability to remove French localization for the English user etc?

Comment: The client is well aware about this...but he is insisting on this...User should get an option to choose the language of the application while using the installation software...ie A french user would get an option to choose english also and vice versa...thanks for your interest...

Comment: I don't understand the "ie" part. I mean, a french user can run the app in the English mode already, if you follow what Apple recommends. (By just opening the System Preferences.) Does the client really insists on removing localizations?